# Amazon SQS Tagging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We are trying to setup Amazon SQS between two AWS applications. Management wants to track cost associated with all Amazon resources. Is it possible to tag Amazon Simple Queue Service resources?

Answer (score 5):

This feature is now supported on SQS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cost-allocation-tags-for-amazon-sqs/

Answer (score 4):

**Tagging for SQS is not yet supported.** Perhaps you may manually calculate using the standard formula with few assumption of number of requests made like number of SQS Request etc.

In my opinion you can enable cost tagging for the AWS Resources which are support and for the remaining you can try having the accountability like misc. charges which can certainly include the SQS.

> - First 1 million Amazon SQS Requests per month are free
> - $0.50 per 1 million Amazon SQS Requests  per month thereafter ($0.00000050 per SQS Request)
> - A single request can have from 1 to 10 messages, up to a maximum total payload of 256KB.
> - Each 64KB ‘chunk’ of payload is billed as 1 request. For example, a single API call with a 256KB payload will be billed as four requests.

Reference : http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/

Comment: Please, make it happen Amazon Web Services ! :(

Answer (score 1):

Please use following AWS cli command to tag you SQS:

aws sqs tag-queue --queue-url  --tags="Key-name=Value","Key-name=Value"

Answer (score 0):

I have created a boto3 script to tag the SQS. Please pass your queue name in tag_sqs_queue()

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sqs')


def get_queue_url(queuename):
    get_url = client.get_queue_url(
    QueueName=queuename
    )


def tag_sqs_queue(queuename):
    response = client.tag_queue(
        QueueUrl=get_queue_url(queuename),
        Tags={
            'Environment': 'Production',
            'Owner': 'Joe Biden'
        }
    )

tag_sqs_queue('<queuname>')
```

script first gets the queue URL and then applies tags.