# How to update/rename a SQS queue name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have created a SQS queue with certain name. Now I want to prefix ='-dev' to the queue name so that its easy for me to identify environment.

Comment: You cannot rename an SQS queue, the name is part of the ARN which is necessarily immutable.

Comment: I don't understand why the downvotes. It was a legitimate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To rename the queue you will have to delete the existing one and recreate it with the new name as you can see in the parameter section

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html

If you want to identify the queue, you can use tags, for more information you can check here

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cost-allocation-tags-for-amazon-sqs/

And in a similar question about queue tagging here:

[Amazon SQS Tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320506/amazon-sqs-tagging)